# Can I keep an unserialisable object between requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created an .NET Core API project. It works but it creates a new object for each `get` request. Where can I save the object so that I can reuse it? I have searched Google and found `Session` but that only seems to store bytes or serialised bytes. I don't think I can serialise the object.

If `doSomeInitialisation()` takes 1 seconds, creating a new `SomeLibrary` at each `get` request when the `arg1` is the same does not seem efficient and `SomeLibrary` is not serialisable so it cannot be stored to the `Session`.

```
[HttpGet("{arg1}/{arg2}")]
public IActionResult Get(string arg1, string arg2)
{
    var someLibrary = new SomeLibrary();
    someLibrary.doSomeInitialisation(arg1);

    return someLibrary.doSomething(arg2);
}
```

Requests

- httpx://..../dog/1
- httpx://..../dog/2
- httpx://..../dog/3
- httpx://..../cat/1
- httpx://..../cat/2

I could reuse the same `SomeLibrary` object for the first three requests.

Comment: How about using a static member of controller to hold your object ?

Comment: I thought about that, but is that a recommended way?

Comment: Considered using `Dependency Injection` using a "Singleton" specification on your `SomeLibrary` object?

Comment: It will work but when thinking about the recommended ways, since this is asp core as Dandre suggested, you can use Singleton service and inject into the controller.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Having initialize methods on your service classes is a code smell and causes [temporal coupling](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you use DI in your project. First of all read this article [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Then you'll realize that you can use following code to register only one instance per application:

```
//Startup.cs
services.AddSingleton<ISomeLibrary>(new SomeLibrary());

....

//controller
public SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISomeLibrary _sl;

    public SomeController(ISomeLibrary sl)
    {
        _sl = sl;
    }

    ...
}
```

**UPDATE:**

According to your last comment you can implement it like this:

```
public interface ISmthResolver
{
    ISomeLibrary Get(string arg);
}

...

public class SmthResolver : ISmthResolver
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<ISomeLibrary>> _instances = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<ISomeLibrary>>();

    public ISomeLibrary Get(string arg) => _instances.GetOrAdd(arg, key => new Lazy<ISomeLibrary>(() => new SomeLibrary())).Value;
}

...

services.AddSingleton<SmthResolver, ISmthResolver>();

...

public class Some
{
    public Some(ISmthResolver sr)
    {
        var sl = sr.Get("arg");
    }
}
```

Also read this [Making ConcurrentDictionary GetOrAdd thread safe using Lazy](https://andrewlock.net/making-getoradd-on-concurrentdictionary-thread-safe-using-lazy/).

Comment: The thing is, I want to cache multiple instances of `SomeLibrary`. As shown in my OP, I want to cache one for "dog" and one for "cat", so in future requests when `arg` is "dog" or "cat", I would not create a new `SomeLibrary`. If I use this DI patthern, should I define/create an object that can hold multiple instances of `SomeLibrary`, (for example, a class that has a `Dictionary<string, SomeLibrary>` field) and use that to `AddSingleton`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try on singleton pattern,but you should be considering that if it fits your demands because singleton pattern is not a good way for all classes.

```
 public class Singleton
    {
        private static string _locker = new object();
        private static Singleton _instance = null;
        public string SerializedString="";

        ///Constructore is called just one time !
        public Singleton(arg1){
         DoSerialization(arg1);
         }
        public static Singleton Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    lock (_locker)
                    {
                        if (_instance == null)
                        {
                            _instance = new Singleton();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }
    private void DoSerialization(arg1){
      this.SerializedString=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arg1)
     }
    }
```

and use it like this

```
var SameInstance=new Singleton(arg1).Instance;
var serialized=SameInstance.SerializedString;
```